# failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Tags: grails

Hey all, I'm building a GRAILS application with a m:m db relation. As I try to show the entries the well known "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role ... no session or session was closed" error is shown.

One class is:

```
class Hazzard{

static hasMany = [warning:Warning]

static constraints = {
    text(size:1..5000)
}

    String name
    String text
    String toxicity
}
```

the other:

```
class Warning{

static hasMany = [hazzard:Hazzard]
static belongsTo = Hazzard

static constraints = {
    text(size:1..5000)
}

    String code
    String text   
}
```

In Hazzard/show the following code works fine

```
<g:each in="${hazzardInstance.warning}" var="p">
<li><g:link controller="Warning" action="show" id="${p.id}">${p?.encodeAsHTML()}</g:link></li>
</g:each>
```

but on other pages the following code will provide the error:

```
<g:set var="haz" value="${Hazzard.get(params.id)}" />
<h1>${haz.name}</h1>
<p>${haz.text}</p>
<h1>Toxiciteit</h1>
<p>${haz.toxicity}</p>
<br/>
<h1>Gevaren(H) en voorzorgen(P)</h1>
<g:each in="${haz.warning}" var="p"> --> This is where the error pops-up
  ${p.text}
</g:each>
```

Any clues on where this fails?

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?

Comment: I'm using GRAILS version: 1.3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more favorable approach to what you're trying to do would be to perform the `get` in the controller and pass the found domain object to the view for rendering. Something like:

```
// MyController.groovy
class MyController {
    def myAction = {
        def haz = Hazzard.get(params.id)
        render(view: 'myview', model: [hazzardInstance: haz])
    }
}

// my/myview.gsp (the view from your second GSP code block)
<h1>${hazzardInstance?.name.encodeAsHTML()}</h1>
...
<h1>Gevaren(H) en voorzorgen(P)</h1>
<g:each in="${hazzardInstance?.warning}" var="p">...</g:each>
```

Doing GORM lookups in the view can sometimes lead to the exception you're getting, although I thought many problems like that had been fixed in more recent versions of Grails. Nonetheless, using a more correct idiom for querying and rendering views will help you to avoid this error.